# Import electron.BrowserWindow in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm trying to get electron (0.37) and typescript (1.8), with Typings, working properly. I'm having trouble with the import of BrowserWindow. In older examples it seems to be a seperate `require('browser-window')`, but in the current version its `electron.BrowserWindow`.

following an example I found my TypeScript is:

```
import electron = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
...
var mainWindow:BrowserWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: main_width, height: main_height});
```

Unfortunately WebStorm and its TypeScript compiler is complaining: "TS2304: Cannot find name BrowserWindow"; specifically at the variable declaration.  if I remove the type declaration from the variable, it works.

```
var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: main_width, height: main_height});
```

...but this seems to defeat the purpose of typescript though?

I've tried a few different ways around this, but cannot get it working properly. For instance, if I do: `import BrowserWindow = Electron.BrowserWindow` the compiler is happy, but the javascript fails because `Electron` (a typescript namespace) isn't defined.

Admittedly I'm new to typescript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> var mainWindow:BrowserWindow

You probably want :

```
var mainWindow:Electron.BrowserWindow
```